# Is there only one unique DPDA that accepts a specific language?

Tags: pushdown-automata

Or is it possible to construct more than one DPDA that accepts exactly the same language?

Comment: Exercise: Find a nontrivial language (e.g. one that isn't finite), and construct a DPDA for it. Now turn that DPDA into a DPDA with more states.

Comment: Another exercise: Construct an infinite number of DPDA for the empty language.

Comment: A better question would be: is there a unique *minimal* DPDA, just as there is a unique minimal DFA?